# Is it expected that split behaves differently with a string than it does with a non-string range<char>?

Tags: c++, split, c++17, range-v3

Given `someString` of type `std::string`, when doing `someString | split(delim)`, delim can be a `char`, i.e. of the `value_type` of the range, or a `std::string`, i.e. a subrange of the range. They both work.

However, if one considers the `std::string` as it was just a range-of-`char`s and decides to see what happens when the range is not a `std::basic_string` but a `std::vector`, they'll see the behavior is different, as given a `std::vector<int> v{/* other ints */, someInt, /* other ints */};`, `v | split(someInt)` will work as expected, but `v | split(std::vector<int>{someInt})` will leave the range unsplit.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/split.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using ranges::to;
using ranges::to_vector;
using namespace ranges::views;
using namespace std::literals;

int main() {
    auto str = "abc def ghi"s;
    {
        std::cout << (str | split(" "s)
                          | join
                          | to<std::string>) << std::endl;
        auto res = str | split(" "s) | join | to<std::string>;
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    {
        std::cout << (str | split(' ')
                          | join
                          | to<std::string>) << std::endl;
        auto res = str | split(' ') | join | to<std::string>;
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;

    auto vec = str | to_vector;
    {

        std::cout << (vec | split(' ')) << std::endl;
        auto res = vec | split(' ') ;
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    {
        std::cout << (vec | split(std::vector<char>{' '})) << std::endl;
        auto res = vec | split(std::vector<char>{' '}) ;
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is this difference expected?

Comment: vector doesn't have any comparison or lookup functions for a subrange while string does.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, but given that comparison or lookup function is not availble, shouldn't we get a compile time error in the 4th case in my example. I mean, based on your observation, `a_vector_of_ints | split(another_possibly_different_vector_of_ints)` could never ever give anything other than a singleton range whose only element is `a_vector_of_ints`. If that's all it can do, then I'm surprised it can even compile.